# How to provide additional initialization for a subclass of namedtuple?

Tags: python, inheritance, tuples

Suppose I have a `namedtuple` like this:

```
EdgeBase = namedtuple("EdgeBase", "left, right")
```

I want to implement a custom hash-function for this, so I create the following subclass:

```
class Edge(EdgeBase):
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.left) * hash(self.right)
```

Since the object is immutable, I want the hash-value to be calculated only once, so I do this:

```
class Edge(EdgeBase):
    def __init__(self, left, right):
        self._hash = hash(self.left) * hash(self.right)

    def __hash__(self):
        return self._hash
```

This appears to be working, but I am really not sure about subclassing and initialization in Python, especially with tuples. Are there any pitfalls to this solution? Is there a recommended way how to do this? Is it fine? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tests have shown that it's not worth to cache the hash value, see
   [issue #9685](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-bugs-list/2013-January/192363.html)

Comment: Side-note: The canonical way to combine hashes is to compute the hash of a `tuple` of the combined values; `tuple` uses a more tested, reliable way of combining hashes than most naive solutions (significantly better than mere multiplication of hashes). So if you just didn't override hash, `tuple`'s default hash would already be correct/efficient (more efficient than anything you'll write because it doesn't execute any Python level byte code at all). Even if this wasn't a `namedtuple`, the correct solution would be `hash((self.left, self.right))`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger good point. This was quite a while ago, but if I remember correctly, the hash-function was chosen like this because the class represented undirected edges, so in this case it the `tuple` approach wouldn't work.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: In that case, the `hash` of a `frozenset` of the values would work. Not as good at producing unique hashes as `tuple`'s hash (`frozenset` just shuffles up the bits predictably, then xors them together), but of course, in this case, that's the goal.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**edit for 2017:** [turns out `namedtuple` isn't a great idea](https://attrs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/why.html#namedtuples). [attrs](https://attrs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is the modern alternative.

```
class Edge(EdgeBase):
    def __new__(cls, left, right):
        self = super(Edge, cls).__new__(cls, left, right)
        self._hash = hash(self.left) * hash(self.right)
        return self

    def __hash__(self):
        return self._hash
```

`__new__` is what you want to call here because tuples are immutable. Immutable objects are created in `__new__` and then returned to the user, instead of being populated with data in `__init__`.

`cls` has to be passed twice to the `super` call on `__new__` because `__new__` is, for historical/odd reasons implicitly a `staticmethod`.

Comment: Why should I prefer this to my solution (this is not meant to be a cynical question, I really want to understand if there are any significant differences)?

Comment: Your solution doesn't use `super`, and therefore will break in any sort of multiple inheritance situation. It doesn't matter if *you* don't use MI; if someone else does, their code will break horribly. It's not difficult to avoid this issue by just using `super` everywhere.

Comment: It's also beneficial to add `__slots__ = ()` to the class. Otherwise `__dict__` will be created, negating memory efficiency of `namedtuple`.

Comment: Setting `__slots__` would break the assignment to _hash and clearly the class isn't readonly as that would also break the assignment to _hash regardless of whether it's done in `__new__`.

Comment: It is worth noting that unlike a pure `namedtuple`, the derived class will actually allow unknown parameters to be set on the instance, which may not be what you want.

Comment: You can do slots = ('_hash',) instead of ().  Someone assigning _hash will still break this class, but you have marked it private, so you have done your job.  Also, I would use + instead of * for the hash function.

Comment: `attrs` cannot be considered "the" modern alternative unless and until it replaces `namedtuple` in the standard library.  Not needing third-party dependencies is still a common design constraint.

Comment: @zwol that's usually a misguided constraint :)  there's lots of tooling available these days for making third-party dependencies a non-issue, like pipenv and pex.

Comment: @zwol also consider that even the python stdlib recognizes its own deficient state: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request has a link to `requests`.

Comment: @habnabit I cannot agree with the assertion that this is a misguided constraint. I'm not interested in discussing it any further.

Comment: @zwol ok! I just want to reiterate that the third-party library situation in python has been rapidly improving. it used to be less good, so I can empathize with the thought.

Comment: **The standard `@dataclasses.dataclass` decorator is the modern alternative** – especially when passed `frozen=True` to enforce immutability ala `tuple` and `namedtuple`. `@dataclass` is well-maintained, well-documented, behaves sensibly under edge cases, and requires *no* third-party dependencies. `attrs` is *not* the modern alternative. @zwol is correct: increasing the fragility of your stack by requiring a new dependency just for dataclass functionality that Python itself already offers out-of-the-box is absurd and dangerous.

Answer (score 5):

In Python 3.7+, you can now use [dataclasses](https://github.com/ericvsmith/dataclasses) to build hashable classes with ease.

**Code**

Assuming `int` types of `left` and `right`, we use the default hashing via `unsafe_hash`<sup>+</sup> keyword:

```
import dataclasses as dc


@dc.dataclass(unsafe_hash=True)
class Edge:
    left: int
    right: int


hash(Edge(1, 2))
# 3713081631934410656
```

Now we can use these (mutable) hashable objects as elements in a set or (keys in a dict).

```
{Edge(1, 2), Edge(1, 2), Edge(2, 1), Edge(2, 3)}
# {Edge(left=1, right=2), Edge(left=2, right=1), Edge(left=2, right=3)}
```

---

**Details**

We can alternatively override the `__hash__` function:

```
@dc.dataclass
class Edge:
    left: int
    right: int

    def __post_init__(self):
        # Add custom hashing function here
        self._hash = hash((self.left, self.right))         # emulates default

    def __hash__(self):
        return self._hash


hash(Edge(1, 2))
# 3713081631934410656
```

Expanding on @ShadowRanger's comment, the OP's custom hash function is not reliable.  In particular, the attribute values can be interchanged, e.g. `hash(Edge(1, 2)) == hash(Edge(2, 1))`, which is likely unintended.

<sub><sup>+</sup>Note, the name "unsafe" suggests the default hash will be used despite being a mutable object.  This may be undesired, particularly within a dict expecting immutable keys.  Immutable hashing can be turned on with the appropriate keywords.  See also more on [hashing logic](https://github.com/ericvsmith/dataclasses/blob/d4c87c663feb0617fd8c7e6fe0a58882c4ccd468/dataclasses.py#L115) in dataclasses and a [related issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue32929).</sub>

Answer (score 4):

The code in the question could benefit from a super call in the `__init__` in case it ever gets subclassed in a multiple inheritance situation, but otherwise is correct.

```
class Edge(EdgeBase):
    def __init__(self, left, right):
        super(Edge, self).__init__(left, right)
        self._hash = hash(self.left) * hash(self.right)

    def __hash__(self):
        return self._hash
```

While tuples are readonly only the tuple parts of their subclasses are readonly, other properties may be written as usual which is what allows the assignment to _hash regardless of whether it's done in `__init__` or `__new__`. You can make the subclass fully readonly by setting it's `__slots__` to (), which has the added benefit of saving memory, but then you wouldn't be able to assign to _hash.