# How do I add datetime.now().isoformat() to NamedTuple's __init__?

Tags: python, datetime, namedtuple

Of course I have tried:

```
class PdfContentRecord(NamedTuple):
    filename: str
    page: int
    cache: dict
    data: dict = dict()
    accessed: str = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        self = super().__new__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.accessed = datetime.now().isoformat()
        return self
```

But I get exactly the same error as [How to provide additional initialization for a subclass of namedtuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624753/how-to-provide-additional-initialization-for-a-subclass-of-namedtuple)

I can't tell if `attrs` can help me (too difficult to comprehend). `dataclasses.dataclass` probably can help, but it only supports Python 3.7.

Or I could write my Class, probably also with `__slots__`...

Edit:

> Did you read the answer in the question you linked?

works with `from collection import namedtuple`, but not `from typing import NamedTuple`.

Comment: You also share the same default data dict between instances, probably a bug.

Comment: @wim It works, thank. But it is hard to backport beyond Python 3.6.

Comment: Did you read the answer in the question you linked?

Comment: @wim Thanks to you, I have found [`__attrs_post_init__ `](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/examples.html#other-goodies)

Comment: @user2357112 `__new__` is just as equally broken.

Comment: @pylang I send it to a database with `record._asdict()`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) you can just use the [`default_factory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field) of a field. If you're using [attrs](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/) you can similarly provide a [factory](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/api.html#attr.ib) callable.

If you're using [`typing.NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple), you should be able to do this with an extra layer of types:

```
from datetime import datetime
from typing import NamedTuple


class _PdfContentRecord(NamedTuple):
    filename: str
    page: int
    cache: dict
    data: dict = None
    accessed: str = None


class PdfContentRecord(_PdfContentRecord):

    def __new__(cls, filename, page, cache, data=None, accessed=None):
        if data is None:
            data = {}
        if accessed is None:
            accessed = datetime.now().isoformat()
        return super().__new__(cls, filename, page, cache, data, accessed)
```

Arguably, though, you lose some of the benefits of using a `NamedTuple` in the first place, and may as well just write the subtype directly.

Comment: Can you explain overriding `__new__` here.  It seems you are able to set the class attributes at class creation, correct?

Comment: Not set them, exactly, but intercept the arguments.  Overriding `__new__` instead of `__init__` is typical when subclassing immutable types such as tuples, datetimes, etc

Answer (score 2):

Quite a beautiful answer, that requires `pip install attrs` (which inspires `dataclass`)

```
import attr

@attr.s
class PdfFileRecord:
    name: str = attr.ib()
    type: str = attr.ib()
    cache: dict = attr.ib()
    data: dict = attr.ib(factory=dict)
    accessed: str = attr.ib(factory=lambda: datetime.now().isoformat())
```

For the [`dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) version, Python 3.7+ or the [backport for Python 3.6](https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses/) is needed.

```
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class PdfFileRecord:
    name: str
    type: str
    cache: dict
    data: dict = dataclasses.field(default_factory=dict)
    accessed: str = dataclases.field(default_factory=lambda: datetime.now().isoformat())
```

Comment: I am using Python 3.7, but I plan to share my code.

Comment: Note: Now that you've fixed your code per @wim, you might have noticed you don't need `__attrs_post_init__` at all. You could just define `accessed` as `accessed: str = attr.ib(init=False, factory=lambda: datetime.now().isoformat())` and now you don't need `__attrs_post_init__` at all (and you've avoided separating the information about the default value from the information about the attribute itself).