# How to initialize a NamedTuple child class different ways based on input arguments?

Tags: python, inheritance, constructor, immutability, namedtuple

I am building a typing.NamedTuple class ([see typing.NamedTuple docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple), or the older [collections.namedtuples docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) it inherits from) that can accept different ways of being initialized.

Why NamedTuple in this case? I want it to be immutable and auto-hashable so it can be a dictionary key, and I don't have to write the hash function.

I understand that I need to use `__new__` rather than `__init__` due to NamedTuples being immutable (for example, [see this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61699471/6501141). I've searched and there are some tidbits out there (e.g. [answers to this question on setting up a custom hash for a namedtuple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3624753/6501141)), but I can't get everything working, I'm getting an error about not being able to overwrite `__new__`.

Here's my current code:

```py
from typing import NamedTuple

class TicTacToe(NamedTuple):
    """A tic-tac-toe board, each character is ' ', 'x', 'o'"""
    row1: str = '   '
    row2: str = '   '
    row3: str = '   '

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f'Enter __new__ with {cls}, {args}, {kwargs}')
        if len(args) == 1 and args[0] == 0:
            new_args = ('   ', '   ', '   ')
        else:
            new_args = args
        self = super().__new__(cls, *new_args, *kwargs)
        return self

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = TicTacToe(('xo ', 'x x', 'o o'))
    print(a)
    b = TicTacToe(0)
    print(b)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Code/lightcc/OpenPegs/test_namedtuple.py", line 4, in <module>
    class TicTacToe(NamedTuple):
  File "C:\Dev\Python37\lib\typing.py", line 1384, 
in __new__
    raise AttributeError("Cannot overwrite NamedTuple attribute " + key)
AttributeError: Cannot overwrite NamedTuple attribute __new__
```

Am I not able to create a separate `__new__` function for a child class that inherits from NamedTuple? It appears from the message that it's attempting to overwrite `__new__` for NamedTuple directly, rather than the TicTacToe class.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid needing to define `__new__()` by defining a [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod). In the sample code below, I've simply named it `make()`. It's analogous to the class method named [`_make()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._make)<sup>✶</sup> that [`collections.namedtype`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) subclasses have.

<sup>✶</sup>This is a common way to provide "alternative constructors" to any class.

Note that I also changed the first call to the function so it passes the arguments properly to the `make()` method.

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class TicTacToe(NamedTuple):
    """A tic-tac-toe board, each character is ' ', 'x', 'o'."""
    row1: str = '   '
    row2: str = '   '
    row3: str = '   '

    @classmethod
    def make(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f'Enter make() with {cls}, {args}, {kwargs}')
        if len(args) == 1 and args[0] == 0:
            new_args = ('   ', '   ', '   ')
        else:
            new_args = args
        self = cls(*new_args, *kwargs)
        return self

if __name__ == '__main__':
#    a = TicTacToe.make(('xo ', 'x x', 'o o'))
    a = TicTacToe.make('xo ', 'x x', 'o o')
    print(a)
    b = TicTacToe.make(0)
    print(b)
```

Output:

```
Enter make() with <class '__main__.TicTacToe'>, ('xo ', 'x x', 'o o'), {}
TicTacToe(row1='xo ', row2='x x', row3='o o')
Enter make() with <class '__main__.TicTacToe'>, (0,), {}
TicTacToe(row1='   ', row2='   ', row3='   ')
```

##### Update

An alternative workaround to not being able to overload the `NamedTuple` subclass' `__new__()` method would be to split the derived class into two  classes, one public and one private, so that the former is no longer a direct subclass of `NamedTuple`.

An advantage of doing it this way, is there's no longer a need to create instances using a special-purpose classmethod like `make()` above.

Here's what I mean:

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class _BaseBoard(NamedTuple):
    """Private base class for tic-tac-toe board."""
    row1: str = '   '
    row2: str = '   '
    row3: str = '   '


class TicTacToe(_BaseBoard):
    """A tic-tac-toe board, each character is ' ', 'x', 'o'."""
    __slots__ = ()  # Prevent creation of a __dict__.

    @classmethod
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f'Enter __new__() with {cls}, {args}, {kwargs}')
        if len(args) == 1 and args[0] == 0:
            new_args = ('   ', '   ', '   ')
        else:
            new_args = args
        self = super().__new__(*new_args, *kwargs)
        return self


if __name__ == '__main__':

    a = TicTacToe('xo ', 'x x', 'o o')
    print(a)
    assert getattr(a, '__dict__', None) is None  # Verify not being created.
    b = TicTacToe(0)
    print(b)
```

Note that this approach is an example of applying Andrew Koenig's [fundamental theorem of software engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering), namely: **"We can solve any problem by introducing an extra level of indirection."**

Comment: A good alternative - basically creating a factory through a classmethod (with `__new__` basically just being the default factory for the class..). This doesn't directly answer my original question though - is it correct that `__new__` is read-only for NamedTuple (I supposed it might not be for namedtuple).

Comment: It _does_ answer the titular question "How to initialize a NamedTuple child class different ways based on input arguments?" — sao I think you should accept it.

Comment: The reason you can't override the `__new__()` method is because the code in the `typing.py` module explicitly checks for, and prohibits it — see the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/typing.py#L1777).

Comment: I accepted because this works and does make a lot of sense. The issue I have is that I'm constantly forgetting to use the `Class.make(x)` method rather than just `Class(x)` (leading to not-immediately-obvious defects). The problem is disallowing the ability to override `__init__` and `__new__` for NamedTuples. This seems unpythonic, as those are the standard way to handle this situation. Too much trying to protect people from themselves.

Comment: LightCC: You're assuming you know why the authors of the `typing` module prohibited overriding `__new__()`. It's possible it was for reasons other than protecting folks from themselves — such as it being incompatible with the implementation of one or more of the features `NamedTuple`s provides. As always, design decisions involve making trade-offs…